# Using induction for function

Tags: induction

http://vvcap.net/db/WIKadCo4Uzu8X6f97cYo.htp$ $

i) $g(0)=0$ since $0+0 = 0$
$p(n) = g(n) = n+n$ is true, as it holds for $n=0$.
$g(k)= k + k$ since inductive step
$g(k+1)=g(k)+2=(k+k)+2=(k+1)+(k+1)$

ii)$g(2\cdot0)=g(0)$
since $g(0)=0+0 $
$g(2\cdot0)=0+0$

hit a stale mate, but can someone check if i've done this right?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question.

Comment: @user113523: Whoever edited the post last - this is not the correct way to do this. If you got the answer you wanted - accept it. If not, but you do not want the question - delete the question. DO NOT edit the question so that the answers make no sense.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is correctm but mathematically it is not really clear written. For example, how do we now that $n\in\mathbb{N}$ in your solution. Also you are talking about the inductive step, where have you defined that? In the second part you need to check if $g(2\cdot (n+1)) = 2g(n+1)$ after the checking of the base case, $n=0$.

ii) Step 1: For $n=0$ we have $$g(2\cdot 0) = g(0) = 0 = 2g(0).$$ So This is correct.

Step 2: Now suppose that $g(2\cdot n) =2g(n)$. We show that $g(2(n+1))=2g(n+1)$.
Now we have with the substitution $m=n+1$:
$$g(2(n+1)) = g(2m) = 2g(m) = 2g(n+1),$$
which was to be shown. So by mathematical induction we have that $g(2n)=2g(n)$ is correct.